# VSTS Variable prompt before release or environment deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a scenario where sometime I need to do a job (update JSON file) for a specific deployments. So wondering if there is feature in CD release pipeline in VSTS where before deploying to a specific environment it ask for values of a specific variables (may be via an email). 
In other words:

1. When ever my release pipeline kick in
2. An email should be sent to me
3. Email would have a form like structure where it will ask me some information to submit. e.g I have a variable name RefreshCache and that should appear as checkbox in the email.
4. Then that response will be considered in the release pipeline (basically as a variable e.g. RefreshCache in my case.

Will be more great if this kind of options be available with Pre-Deployment approval:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you could use variable groups that are scoped to a specific environment to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't such feature in VSTS. You may submit a [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/):